# multiple passes zipped not recognised by apple wallet

Tags: ios, apple-wallet

I'm following this guide: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/distributing_and_updating_a_pass#3793284

I've managed to create the .pkpasses file that contains multiple .pkpass that are all valid on their own. The problem is when opening it with an apple device the file is being downloaded as a normal file and is not added to wallet.

I'm using this library for the pkpass generation: https://github.com/thenextweb/passgenerator

Is there any other way to troubleshoot this?

My download code is below, this is using laravel

The code above this would be the one that will create the passes, and those work individually.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zipFilePath = public_path() . '/passes.zip';

        if ($zip->open($zipFilePath, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
            foreach ($passes as $index => $pkpass) {
                $zip->addFromString('pass_' . $index . '.pkpass', $pkpass);
            }
            $zip->close();

            // Rename the zip file to a .pkpass file
            rename($zipFilePath, public_path() . '/passes.pkpasses');
        }

return response()->download(public_path() . '/passes.pkpasses', 'passes.pkpasses', ['Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.apple.pkpasses'])->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: Is your server setting the right mime type. My guess is that it isn't.

Comment: @Paulw11 it is set to `['Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.apple.pkpasses']` not sure how I can verify that though when it's downloaded

Comment: Use curl or even developer mode in safari